# Loading large models in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have successfully used three.js to display 3D models, I used ObjLoader and MtlLoader to complete this task, the snippet shows a portion of the working code, but **loading large model files takes too much time**, and I can't afford this much time. Is it possible to solve this issue? Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image: My working code]

Comment: What ever way you look at it, your file 3d needs to be downloaded. So your only real option is to try to make your 3d file smaller. You could try to reduce the complexity of your 3d model, or maybe try using a different file format. The size of your textures may be playing a part here too, but without seeing your model or textures, we can only guess.

Comment: Is there a way or a special format that allows me to load low resolution at first and start filling out with higher resolution as time goes on?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: You would also have to ask yourself... If it is taking so long to download, then it must be a very complex model, would it not also hamper performance than too? How large is the .obj file you are loading?

Comment: I can't see a code snippet, just an image. Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The screenshot is just merely showing that I'm using objloader and mtlloader, and there's nothing actually to do with the code. The model is usually 100M to 150M, so it usually takes too much time. Is there maybe a way to lower the quality?